# Mysql & Php help required

Tags: php, mysql, function

So i am using smarty templates and i had added a new column name track_id inside the database but its giving me an error that is "Notice: Undefined index: trackorderid in C:\xampp\htdocs\zeno\includes\order_place.php on line 27" but i have defined index already ?"

```
 db_query("insert into ".ORDERS_TABLE." (order_time,track_id, cust_firstname, cust_lastname, cust_email, cust_country, cust_zip, cust_state, cust_city, cust_address, cust_phone) values ('".get_current_time()."',,'".$_POST["trackorderid"]."','".$_POST["first_name"].‌​"','".$_POST["last_name"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["country"]."','".$_P‌​OST["zip"]."','".$_POST["state"]."','".$_POST["city"]."','".$_POST["address"]."',‌​'".$_POST["phone"]."');") or die (db_error());
```

Comment: trackorderid is not in a POST variable, check the name in the form where it is posted from.

Comment: My guess is tha tthe form that supplies the data doesn't have a field with that name, but who knows? You've not posted enough information.

Comment: i just checked it is the post variable

Comment: <tr><td colspan=2 align=right><font color=red>*</font>Order ID</td><td><input type='text' name='trackorderid' value='{php}echo rand(2112,1200);{/php}' disabled></td></tr>

Comment: The above one is the form code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not an error it is just a notice php is notifying you that  trackorderid is not exist inside your $_POST super global array but you are still trying to access it . Please check your form which posts data to this query because it looks like you have a syntax mistake in the name field of form element.

Also not related to your question but another suggestion always use

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["trackorderid"])
```

to escape data while using it in your mysql queries otherwise your code will be open to mysql injection attacks.

Comment: i checked , its seems to be correct?

Comment: @user3296356 I just saw your html code. Change disabled to readonly in your html and you are done :)

Comment: @user3296356 One more comment on that in order to make it valid html use readonly="readonly" not only readonly.

Comment: its say You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1812','test','test','test@test.com','Canada','1234','test','test','testing','12' at line 1

Comment: Got what was the error :D @Madcoe you save me so much today :D thanks alot alot alot :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a query error you had

```
"insert into ".ORDERS_TABLE." 
(
    order_time,
    track_id, 
    cust_firstname, 
    cust_lastname, 
    cust_email, 
    cust_country, 
    cust_zip, 
    cust_state, 
    cust_city, 
    cust_address, 
    cust_phone
) 
values 
(
    '".get_current_time()."',
    ,'".$_POST["trackorderid"]."',
    '".$_POST["first_name"].‌​"',
    '".$_POST["last_name"]."',
    '".$_POST["email"]."',
    '".$_POST["country"]."',
    '".$_P‌​OST["zip"]."',
    '".$_POST["state"]."',
    '".$_POST["city"]."',
    '".$_POST["address"]."',‌
    ​'".$_POST["phone"]."'
)"


'".get_current_time()."',,'".$_POST["trackorderid"]."',
```

Here you have 2 commas the correct query is

```
"insert into ".ORDERS_TABLE." 
(
    order_time,
    track_id, 
    cust_firstname, 
    cust_lastname, 
    cust_email, 
    cust_country, 
    cust_zip, 
    cust_state, 
    cust_city, 
    cust_address, 
    cust_phone
) 
values 
(
    '".get_current_time()."',
    '".$_POST["trackorderid"]."',
    '".$_POST["first_name"].‌​"',
    '".$_POST["last_name"]."',
    '".$_POST["email"]."',
    '".$_POST["country"]."',
    '".$_P‌​OST["zip"]."',
    '".$_POST["state"]."',
    '".$_POST["city"]."',
    '".$_POST["address"]."',‌
    ​'".$_POST["phone"]."'
)"
```

Also make sure all the POST data is available before you put the data in query and most important sanitize the data using mysql_real_escape_string or use PDO

Answer (score 0):

This more or less looks like a name-field issue. Has nothing to do with the database, or query. Check the form which is making the post request and make sure you have the field with name 'trackorderid' within the form. Also, make use of print_r($_POST) just before you write the insert query, to make sure $_POST['trackorderid'] is not empty.

Comment: Not just POST data it has something to do with query ('".get_current_time()."',,'".$_POST["trackorderid"]."', check this line

Comment: I just checked :D you help me too :D